# Patch for a component in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working with Primefaces 6.2 because our project still runs on JDK 6.
The migration to JDK 8+ is planned but not possible in short term. This means that I can not migrate to a higher version of primefaces.

In Primefaces 6.2 there is a little bug with the autocomplete feature and I wanted to fix it by modifying the autcomplete.js file.

Is it possible to remove a file ( autocomplete.js ) from the generated components.js file and provide a custom one?

I've seen that primefaces compresses the JS file and adds all of them to a file components.js.

Thus, I would need to prevent the file to be added/compressed and then find a way to add mine instead.

Comment: Can you not override the javascript method?  I have done this in the past

Comment: Yup, it's indeed just overridable.

Comment: If you put above the JS you want to fix I can show you how to patch the file externally easily with a MonkeyPatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it or use omnifaces `CDNResourceHandler` and point primefaces resources to your own destination where you can edit the file directly.

**JS override Example**

```
if(PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel)
{
    // use proxy pattern to not duplicate original code
    (function() 
    {
        var proxied = PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus;

        PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus = function()
        {
            if (this.jq.hasClass("disable-autofocus"))
                return;

            return proxied.apply(this, arguments); 
        };
    })();
}
```

**CDNResourceHandler**

You can change the primefaces resource lookup using the CDN resourcehandler of [OmniFaces](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler). Copy the original javascript file to a different location, edit it and setup the CDN handler in web config like:

`primefaces:components.js=/resources/primefaces/6.2/components.js`
`